# Sum of subtracted numbers in a different way

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have big table where I need to sum the numbers for different months. I put the correct sum numbers in last column where you can check it out. I need the formula which will show us result exactly like that.

[image]

As you see there are some different conditions which doesnt let me to use just `sum` or `sumifs`. Sum of the numbers are the result of subtraction of each months except if the next month has bigger values or if the numbers are the same for all months.  Maybe anybody can help me on this ? is there any way to get the Sum values with one formula ?

Comment: Right now, at least to me, it's a bit unclear. Please include your own attempt, and show us how for example you got to 9 in the first row.

Comment: if the A2 > B2 then subtract and plus the nex one (B2>C2) till the end. if the numbers are equal then dont do anything. if the A2<B2 then do nothing. if A2 is blank then do nothing also. This gives you what you need actually but I am unable to make the formula what Said right now.

Comment: Add additional rows that match with your condition. According to your sample, On Row 11 Column B place `=IF(A1>B1,A1-B1,0)`. Drag this formula for your selection (B11 to J18) and add the `SUM` formulas at the end. You can try with a formula, but there will be too many if conditions. Is that ok for you?

Comment: Yes that worked well, but would be amazingly helpfull if I would be able to use one formula even there will be too many ifs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to shift your sum column to the right, then try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((COLUMN(B2:K2)<11)*(A2:I2>B2:K2),0),A2:J2-B2:K2)
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/xfNfd98) Check this image please. there are issues with calculation on 2,6 and 7 rows. rest is correcct.

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan, as I mentioned, you need to shift your sum column to the right, as per my screenshot.

Comment: that worked finally. Thank you Very much! the only problem is that , I did a mistake in the 9th row. the sum should be 98 not 94. It was my mistake because if the number was 5 and the next cell is blank or 0 it means we should subtract 5 from 5 in order to get blank or 0.

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan, see edited answer. Note, how this made the answer in row 4 change to.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I Appreciate your help and time. Completely saved my life!

Comment: there is an issue with this formula unfortunately. In some parts there is something like picture is th result, however it shouldn't be like that. [link](https://ibb.co/G3RCg2z) - in this link as you see the result is 6, which it shouldn't. the correct number was  **20**

I only used your formula as you mentioned.

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan, seems to me you using the wrong ranges in that formula ;), correct would be: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((COLUMN(E1:AP1)<COLUMN(AP1))*(D1:AO1>E1:AP1),0),D1:AO1-E1:AP1)`

Comment: Thank you so much worked like charm! Sorry for disturbing you again. I appreciate..